# All sections show over fixed header when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed

I have a fixed header at the top of all sections in home page. but when i am scrolling, all contents and sections goes over(above) the fixed header and the header remains like a background.

How to fix this that all images and contents go under the fixed header?

*CSS*

```
#header-wrapper { 
   width:100%; 
   float:none;
   background:#09f;
   z-index:999px;
   position:fixed;
   top:100;
}
```

Comment: this is my css code
#header-wrapper {   width:100%; float:none; background:#09f; z-index:999px;  position:fixed; top:100; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some problem with `z-index` as per your description

This might help

Mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, a new stacking context is created by `position: fixed`, even when `z-index` is `auto`.

So the stacking context hierarchy looks like this:

- document root (z-index `0`)

  - `#element` (z-index `9998`)
  - `#element2` (z-index `0`)

    - `.aboveElement` (z-index `9999`)
    - `.belowElement` (z-index `9997`)

You cannot compare `9998` with `9999` or `9997` to determine stacking order.  Instead, `9999` is compared with `9997` to determine which of `.aboveElement` and `.belowElement` is further in front, and then once everything inside `#element2` is stacked in that context, it's treated as a single layer at z-index `0` which gets stacked behind `#element` at z-index `9998`.

Read [the stacking context in mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context.)

Read [the stacking change for `fixed` elements in Chrome](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
position: fixed;
Top: 100px;
left: 0;
z-index: 9999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   position: fixed;
```

to the parent element of the fixed header and this should work

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` property should be simply integer value without `px`, it cannot have units because it simply specifies order of an element.

Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)